# creating blob - java heap space

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I'm passing a multipartFile from controller to service and inside the service 
trying to create Blob from this multipartFile. The problem is that the files I'm using are really big (4-5 gb ) and I get "java heap space" error ( no I cannot allocate more memory to the application)

Is there any way to stream it or sth? 
I'm using java 7

service code:

```
def uploadFile(MultipartFile file){
    Sql sql = utilsService.retrieveSQLFromDataSource()
    Blob blob = dataSource.connection.createBlob()
    blob.setBytes(1, file.bytes)
    ...
}
```

Comment: See [setBinaryStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html#setBinaryStream(long))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the relevant part - I'm simulation a large BLOB by writing repeatedly a small chunk.

The important part ist the creation of the [temporary BLOB](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/905/jdbc-javadoc/oracle/sql/BLOB.html#createTemporary(java.sql.Connection,%20boolean,%20int)).

```
def bytes = data.getBytes()
BLOB tempBlob = BLOB.createTemporary(con, true, BLOB.DURATION_SESSION);
def os = tempBlob.setBinaryStream(0);
20000.times { 
 os.write(bytes,0,bytes.size())
}
os.close()
int len = tempBlob.length()
println "length $len"

stmt.setBLOB (1,tempBlob)

stmt.execute()
```